# Create a pattern that looks like this in a file with n number of lines

Tags: python

Create a pattern that looks like this in a file with n number of lines.

```
def make_pattern(file_path, n):
    """
    Create a pattern that looks like this in a file with n number of lines

    Below is the result of make_pattern(file_path, 5)
    *
    ##
    ***
    ####
    *****

    :param file_path:
    :param n: Number of lines to follow this pattern
    :return:
    """

    pass
```

Comment: can you show us something that you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
def make_pattern(file_path, n):
    with open(file_path,'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(['*'*(i+1) if (i+1)%2 else '#'*(i+1) for i in range(n)])) # write each string in the list joined by a newline

make_pattern("t.txt", 5)
```

Output file (`t.txt`):

```
*
##
***
####
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_pattern(file_path,n):
    i=0
    str=''
    while i <= n:
        if i%2 == 0:
            str+='#'*i+"\n"
        else:
            str+='*'*i+"\n"
        i=i+1

    f=open(file_path,"w")
    f.write(str)
    f.close()
```